# Python: create nested dictionary from parent-child mapping

Tags: python, dictionary

I have child-parent mapping as follows:

```
{4:6,
 6:9,
 7:6,
 5:6,
 8:9,
 11:9,
 10:9,
 12:10,
 13:10}
```

I want to create following nested dictionary using above:

```
{"id":9,
 "children":[
             {"id":6,
              "children":[
                          {"id":4,
                           "children":[]},
                          {"id":5,
                           "children":[]},
                          {"id":7,
                           "children":[]},
                         ]
              },
              {"id":10,
              "children":[
                          {"id":12,
                           "children":[]},
                          {"id":13,
                           "children":[]},
                         ]
              },
              {"id":11,
              "children":[]
              },
              {"id":8,
              "children":[]
              }
              ]
}
```

I am able to figure out how I can do it if in place of having keys as "id" and values as 9,6,etc , I have values as keys. Please help me with the above format.

Comment: How is `9` parent of `6`, but `7` child of `6` ?

Comment: Why not reverse the dictionary...I mean interchange key and value. As you said you can solve that way. Right?

Comment: @AnandSKumar these are just ids and can be parent/child of any other node. No such ordering is there. Does this answer your question?

Comment: In your **child-parent** mapping there are following entries `6:9`,
 `6:7`. But in your expected output 9 is **parent** of 6, but 7 is **child** of 6. That's the inconsistency Anand told you about.

Comment: if no such ordering is there, how would we find out which is parent and which is child?

Comment: 6:9, 6:7, check this part twice please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to my query.

I converted the child-parent mapping to a list of tuples as follows:

```
queue_tuples= [(6,9,1),(11,9,1),(8,9,1),(10,9,1),(5,6,2),(7,6,2),(4,6,2),(12,10,2),(13,10,2)]
root = 9
```

Following is the code:

```
pGraph = {"id":root,"children":[]}

for tuple in queue_tuples:
    level = tuple[2]
    g = pGraph["children"]
    for i in range(level-1):
        for e in g:
            if tuple[1]==e["id"]:
                g = e["children"]
    flag = 0
    for e in g:
        if tuple[0]==e["id"]:
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag==0:
        g.append({"id":tuple[0],"children":[]})
print pGraph
```